# Is the quadratic residue the only restriction?

Tags: prime-factorization, quadratic-residues, big-numbers

I still search without success for a prime factor of the huge number $$2\uparrow \uparrow 4+3\uparrow \uparrow 4$$

Another way to write this is $$3^{3^{3^3}}+2^{2^{2^2}}=3^{3^{27}}+65536=3^{7625597484987}+65536$$
Since it can be written as $a^2+3b^2$ with coprime positive integers $a,b$ , we can conclude that a prime factor must have residue $-3$. Since $3$ is obviously impossible , the prime factors must have the form $3k+1$. According to my search there is no prime factor below $3\cdot 10^{11}$ (doublechecks are of course welcome!)

> Is there any other restriction using the large exponent $3^{27}$ ? Or can we do no better than to check all primes of the form $3k+1$ until we find a factor ?

Comment: Can you tell what your strange number with the arrows means?

Comment: @trula See [Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: Thanks John. I learned something-

Comment: There is no prime $p < 12\cdot 10^{12}$ of the form $3k+1$ that divides this number.

Comment: @jorisperrenet Thank you. My computer and PARI/GP are just too slow although I improved the trial division with some trick.

Comment: I only arrived at the humble $4\cdot 10^{11}$. I need another computer and faster tools.

Comment: @jorisperrenet I hope you continue the search and report a factor , if found.

Comment: You also get that $2$ is a cubic residue mod $p$, so by cubic reciprocity (and since $p$ is 1 mod 3), $p$ is of the form $a^2+27b^2$. It’s honestly kinda strange that there are no small factors here - feels like we’re missing something fundamental.

Comment: 7 mod 12 means the 1 mod 6 or 5 mod 6 factors are opposite parity index